# Snakemake optional output with expand()

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am new to Snakemake, and I'm wondering if I'm able to put optional output files in a snakemake rule while using `expand()`.

I'm using `bowtie2-build` to create an indexing of my reference genome, but depending on the genome size, bowtie2 creates indexing files with different extensions: `.bt2` for small genomes, and `.bt21` for big genomes.

I have the following rule:

```
rule bowtie2_build:
    """
    """
    input:
        "reference/"+config["reference_genome"]+".fa"
    output:
                                                                   # every possible extension in expand
        expand("reference/"+config["reference_genome"]+"{suffix}", suffix=[".1.bt2", ".2.bt2", ".3.bt2", ".4.bt2", ".rev.1.bt2", ".rev.2.bt2", ".1.bt21", ".2.bt21", ".3.bt21", ".4.bt21", ".rev.1.bt21", ".rev.2.bt21"])
    params:
        output_prefix=config["reference_genome"]
    shell:
        "bowtie2-build {input} reference/{params.output_prefix}"
```

But now, snakemake will always look for output with all extensions, which will give an error while running, because only files with either one of the two extensions `.bt2` or `.bt21` are actually created depending on genome size.

I have tried to use regex like so:

```
output:
        "reference/"+config["reference_genome"]+"{suffix, \.(1|2|3|4|rev)\.(bt2|bt21|1|2)\.?(bt2|bt21)?}"
```

And this works, but I feel like there should be an easier way for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are making things more complicated than necessary. Bowtie2 (the aligner) takes in input the prefix of the index files and it will find the actual index files by itself. So I wouldn't list the index files as output of any rule. Just use a flag file to indicate that indexing has been completed. For example:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sample}.sam', sample= ['A', 'B', 'C']),

rule bowtie_build:
    input:
        fa= 'genome.fa',
    output:
        touch('index.done'), # Flag file
    params:
        index_prefix= 'genome',
    shell:
        r"""
        bowtie2-build {input.fa} {params.index_prefix}
        """

rule bowtie_align:
    input:
        idx= 'index.done',
        fq1= '{sample}.R1.fastq.gz',
    output:
        sam= '{sample}.sam',
    params:
        index_prefix= 'genome'
    shell:
        r"""
        bowtie2 -x {params.index_prefix} -U {input.fq1} -S {output.sam}
        """
```

Comment: Oh wow this is definitely a smart solution, thanks! One question though: In your example, you request 3 .sam files, but they all use the same flag file "index.done". Does that work? Because to me, it would now seem like that once the first sample has created the "index.done" file, it will already be there for the other samples, so `bowtie_align` won't be dependent anymore of `bowtie_build` for those samples, and it therefore not creating those index files? Or is this not an issue

Comment: *Does that work?* Yes. `bowtie_align` depends on files `index.done` and `{sample}.R1.fastq.gz`. It doesn't matter where these files come from. Of course, `index.done` presumes that the actual index files also exist but unless you delete them `bowtie_align` will work.

Comment: I just now tested it myself and it worked, thank you! This is a lot cleaner than what I tried using regex.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is to rename the files with a different extension. It will print an error if such file does not exist, but you might consider this a feature...:

```py
rule bowtie2_build:
    input:
        "reference/"+config["reference_genome"]+".fa"
    output:
        expand("reference/"+config["reference_genome"]+"{suffix}", suffix=[".1.bt2", ".2.bt2", ".3.bt2", ".4.bt2", ".rev.1.bt2", ".rev.2.bt2"])
    params:
        output_prefix=config["reference_genome"],
        file_name = "reference/"+config["reference_genome"],
    shell:
        """
        bowtie2-build {input} reference/{params.output_prefix}
        mv -v {params.file_name}.1.bt21 {params.file_name}.1.bt2
        mv -v {params.file_name}.2.bt21 {params.file_name}.2.bt2
        mv -v {params.file_name}.3.bt21 {params.file_name}.3.bt2
        # etc... it's also possible to put this in a bash loop
        """
```

In other examples, where the input file has information about the output, e.g. if the genome sequence size is known from the outset, then one option is to generate two rules, `bowtie2_build` and `bowtie2_build_big`, that will specify different extensions.

Comment: Bowtie2 goes for the "big" file extension when the reference is longer than ~4billion nucleotides, but beforehand I won't know if the genome sequence will be big or small. I might be able to check by file size, but I would prefer to just to be able to tell bowtie2 to create an index and it deciding itself what to do, and Snakemake to be compatible with whatever extension bowtie2 created.

Comment: I see, thanks, is it necessary for downstream analysis that these different extensions are maintained? (if not, maybe including a "mv -v " inside the shell directive would help)

Comment: The different extensions don't have to be maintained, but what do you mean with "mv -v"? My Unix command knowledge isn't too great and -v seems to verbose what's being done.

Comment: I updated the answer, it's not great but might be useful...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a use for [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution). With checkpoints, the DAG will be reevaluated after the checkpoint's execution. You could do something like this:

```
from glob import glob

def get_ref_index(wildcards):
    """Returns the reference index for wildcards"""
    checkpoints.bowtie2_build.get()  # Checks to see if the checkpoint rule has been run, might be an issue without wildcards
    suffix=[".1.bt2", ".2.bt2", ".3.bt2", ".4.bt2", ".rev.1.bt2", ".rev.2.bt2", ".1.bt21", ".2.bt21", ".3.bt21", ".4.bt21", ".rev.1.bt21", ".rev.2.bt21"]
    ref_files = glob.glob("reference/" + config["reference_genome"] + "*") # List files with reference genome pattern
    
    for ref in ref_files:
        suffix = ref.split(".", 1)[1]  # Split on first period to grab all suffixes
        if suffix in suffixes:
            return ref
    
checkpoint bowtie2_build:
    input:
        "reference/"+config["reference_genome"]+".fa"
    output:
        touch("reference/"+config["reference_genome"]+".done")  # Breadcrumb file to link to downstream rules, since we don't know what indexes we'll get
    params:
        output_prefix=config["reference_genome"]
    shell:
        "bowtie2-build {input} reference/{params.output_prefix}"
        
rule donwstream_rule:
    input:
        ref = "reference/"+config["reference_genome"]+".fa"
        ref_index = get_ref_index
        ref_index_done = "reference/"+config["reference_genome"]+".done"
    output:
        foo = "bar"
    shell:
        "touch bar"
```

Comment: Checkpoints seem like something that could work, but then what am I supposed to request in my all rule? Because if I test right now by requesting `"reference/MacaNPV_99.1.bt2"` and running Snakemake, it gives an error: `Missing input files for rule all:
reference/MacaNPV_99.1.bt2` (MacaNPV_99 is the name of the reference)

Comment: You could just point to the index done file.